# Why are these "this" and "that" variables both undefined?

Tags: javascript, this

Why in the below code are both:

```
this.fadeTime
that.fadeTime
```

undefined, and what is the best way to save internal variables like this in a Javascript class?

```
var SITE = SITE || {};
SITE.initialize = function() {

    var fadeTime = 100;
    that = this;

    $('li#linkHome').click(function() {
        resetPageLinks();
        $('li#linkHome').addClass('active');
        resetPages();
        console.log(this.fadeTime); //undefined
        console.log(that.fadeTime); //undefined
        $('div#pageHome').fadeIn(that.fadeTime);
    });
    $('li#linkInfo').click(function() {
        resetPageLinks();
        $('li#linkInfo').addClass('active');
        resetPages();
        $('div#pageInfo').fadeIn(that.fadeTime);
    });
    $('li#linkAbout').click(function() {
        resetPageLinks();
        $('li#linkAbout').addClass('active');
        resetPages();
        $('div#pageAbout').fadeIn(that.fadeTime);
    });

    function resetPageLinks() {
        $('ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
    }

    function resetPages() {
        $('div.sitePage').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `SITE.fadeTime` defined? It's not in the code you've posted here.

Comment: I just call SITE.initialize() to run it, I have this setup so that all my variables and methods inside the class don't conflict with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your "click" handlers are invoked, `this` will refer to the DOM element involved. Because DOM elements generally don't have a "fadeTime" property, the value is `undefined`.

Your declaration of "that" is missing the `var` keyword. The variable is therefore global.  It refers to the "SITE" object if that "initialize" function is invoked in the likely way:

```
SITE.initialize();
```

However, the variable "fadeTime" is a local variable, not a property of the "SITE" object. Therefore, referring to "fadeTime" as a property of the "SITE" object also gives you `undefined`.

In the "initialize" function, you could do this:

```
var that = this;

this.fadeTime = 100;
```

Then references to "fadeTime" as a property of "that" would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call fadeTime since it is in the scope of your initialize function. this.fadeTime or that.fadetime are indeed not there because you do not assign the variable on the this scope.

As a sidenote, your fadeTime variable seems more like a constant. In JS it is common to use all caps variable names to define a constant:

```
var MY_CONSTANT = "some-value";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `that` refers to `SITE`, even in the event handler functions. Therefore, `that.fadeTime` refers to `SITE.fadeTime` -- but `SITE.fadeTime` is never defined.

Instead, you can either do:

```
$('div#pageHome').fadeIn(fadeTime);
```

in your event listeners, to refer to the `fadeTime` variable you declared in the lexical scope of `initialize`, or you can do

```
this.fadeTime = 100;
```

at the top of `initialize` to set `SITE.fadeTime` (and therefore set `that.fadeTime` as well).

Answer (score 0):

when you mark the variable with var then it's a local variable. when you wanna create a instance variable which you can access with this you have to declare the variable with

this.fadeTime = 100;

instead of

var fadeTime = 100;